# Using TortoiseSVN to paste files from one directory to checked-out directory gives "error: file already exists"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I checked out some code into `C:\checkedout`. I have modified code with the same name as that in `C:\modified`. I copied the files in `C:\modified`, went to `C:\checkedout` and right-clicked->TortoiseSVN->paste, but got an error saying `Subversion reported an error: file already exists`. How can I place the modified files from `modified` to `checkedout`?

Comment: You're using version control wrong. Check out the files into `Checkedout`. Make your changes there, in that folder, and then check the changed files back into the repo.

Comment: But I already made the changes in `modified` though. And I changed a lot of files. So it would not be convenient to make the changes in `checkedout` and would be alot easier if I could somehow paste the files from `modified` to `checkedout`

Comment: If you'd started out doing it the right way in the first place, you wouldn't be having this problem. :-)

Comment: I originally checked out the repo into `modified`. While I was changing some files, the other team I was working with made their own changes to the repo, which is why I checked it out in to `checkedout`. So that's why I need to merge my changes with their latest one

Comment: When that happened, you should have just done an Update on your existing `Checkedout` folder, which would have applied the updates from other people. I'd suggest you search for the SVN Red Book (available online or for download) to learn to use it properly.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having, anyway. I don't know what *Using Tortoise SVN to copy/paste files* means. Tortoise SVN is an extension to Windows explorer, but it doesn't have anything to do with copy/pasting the files. Select the files in `Modified`, hit Ctrl+C to copy them, navigate to the `Checkedout` folder and hit Ctrl+V to paste the files in. When Windows asks you if you want to overwrite, say yes.

Answer (score 0):

You only need specific Subversion tools to manipulate local files when you're doing something that affects file history (add, remove, copy, move or rename) and TortoiseSVN will helpfully do it for you in the first two cases.

What you're trying to do is basically editing local files so just go ahead as you'd do if you weren't using version control at all.

Alternatively, you can copy the entire `.svn` folder from `C:\checkedout` to `C:\modified`. If nothing goes wrong during the copy (e.g. some files fail to copy due to being locked by another process), you'll have a second identical working copy where you can commit from.